# Enable SELinux on boot

Tags: ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I've just installed SELinux via `apt-get install -y selinux`.

I *understand* that Ubuntu uses AppArmor by default and I *understand* that SELinux removes AppArmor, but I'd like to live with SELinux for a while to learn the ropes and harden my system by hand. Best way to learn something is to dive in, right?

After a reboot, SELinux is still showing as `Disabled`:

```
$ getenforce
Disabled
```

How do I get SELinux enabled on boot?

Comment: Might be in `/etc/selinux/config`, take a look there.

Comment: `SELINUX=permissive ; SELINUXTYPE=ubuntu` not sure about the last bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had to pass the following init parameters to my kernel on boot:

```
selinux security=selinux
```

Don't forget to relabel your filesystem, engage permissive at first, and only then engage enforcing.